# Disable Dockerfile creating during OpenAPI openapitools/openapi-generator-cli build process

Tags: dockerfile, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am using the `OpenAPI openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` tool via the `npm` package, to create `python-flask` based output code. The process works file, and the output code creates the required files. As part of the build process, the openapi-generator-cli tool also creates a default Dockerfile in the output directory. We already have our own Dockerfile, and don't need this Dockerfile created. However, I cannot see any flag, or config option to switch off the building of this file.

I know I can rename our own Dockerfile to something else and specify this file during the container image build, etc. But it would be nice to stop the Dockerfile being creating and causing confusion.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to use an [ignore file](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization#ignore-file-format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems @Helen was correct the answer is to add the Dockerfile to the `.openapi-generator-ignore` file, as can be seen from the log output from running the `generate` command;

```
src/Dockerfile (Ignored by rule in ignore file.)
```

Thanks